# Using cookies to implement progress bar

Tags: php, ajax, cookies

I have a PHP script that takes awhile to run and I want to alert the user of its progress. I'm having trouble implementing this through using cookies. The code I have now is as follows:

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '#pop_db', function() {
    $.post(
        "pop_db.php",
        function(data) {
            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            if(response.code == "success") {
                // success
            } else if(response.code == "failure") {
                // failure
            }
        }
    );

    setInterval(function() { get_user_updates(); }, 5000);
});

function get_user_updates() {
$.post(
    "get_user_update.php",
    function(data) {
        var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        if(response.code == "success") {
            // success
        } else if(response.code == "failure") {
            // failure
        }
    }
);
}
```

The pop_db.php file takes care of doing the PHP work that's taking awhile. In it I set a cookie so I can fetch it on the interval:

```
require_once('includes/database.php');
$dbh = db_connect();

$response = array();
$response['code'] = "success";

setcookie('users_to_update', /*some value */, time() + 120);
setcookie('users_updated', 0, time() + 120);

// do lots of work in a loop

$_COOKIE['users_updated'] += 1;        

echo json_encode($response);
```

The get user update file is very simple:

```
$response = array();
$response['code'] = "success";

$response['users_to_update'] = $_COOKIE['users_to_update'];
$response['users_updated'] = $_COOKIE['users_updated'];

echo json_encode($response);
```

So all of this doesn't work though. The interval seems to run after the first POST request to populate the database is finished.

I've tried using a DB table to accomplish this but ran into similar problems.

Is there some conceptual thing I'm missing here or does anyone notice something wrong with my code?

Comment: The cookie value is sent to the user via the `Set-Cookie` HTTP header when the page output is finally sent. This isn't going to happen until your script has finished processing, which is why you won't see any progress until it's done. What problems did you run into when tracking in the DB? Have you tried using `$_SESSION` instead of `$_COOKIE`?

Comment: @JonathanS. I tried using session and the db. I think the problem with the db was that the php script uses the db constantly and wouldn't let the other script query it for updates. Sessions seemed to give me the same problem as the cookie is now